# How do I filter associated table OR parent on sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

How do I filter child (associated) OR parent tables on sequelize?

I want select data by creation date of child, but if parent table has no child, I want to select by parent's creation date.

So I need filter to compare parent and child fields.

For example:
Is there a way to perform the following query with sequelize without using literals?

```
SELECT * FROM owner, car
WHERE (car.owner_id IS NULL AND car.created_at=NOW())
OR (car.owner_id IS NOT NULL AND owner.created_at=NOW())
```

I could not add a include inside Op.OR.

I also tried the following code, but it consider only parent's created_at field:

```
where: {
  [Op.or]: {
    [Op.and]: {
      owner_id: null,
      created_at: {
        [Op.between]: [startOfDay(searchDate), endOfDay(searchDate)],
      },
    },
    [Op.and]: {
      owner_id: { [Op.not]: null },
      created_at: {
        [Op.between]: [startOfDay(searchDate), endOfDay(searchDate)],
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the name of you models are `Car` and `Owner`:

```
Owner.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Car
    }
  ],
  attributes: ['some_attribute', 'another_attribute'], //Filter attributes
  where: {
    [Op.or]: {
      [Op.and]: {
        '$Car.owner_id$': { [Op.is]: null },
        '$Car.created_at$': {
          [Op.between]: [startOfDay(searchDate), endOfDay(searchDate)],
        },
      },
      [Op.and]: {
        '$Car.owner_id$': { [Op.not]: null },
        created_at: { // This attribute is referencing owner's created_at
          [Op.between]: [startOfDay(searchDate), endOfDay(searchDate)],
        },
      }
    }
  }
})
```

You can reference `Car` inside the where clause with the '$$' string, see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you, Fernando!
It worked!
But we had to make a little change on the code above. We had to remove both Op.And.